# Why is this jquery .css style not being applied?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to understand why the `<ul>` element .css property is not being applied from the Debugger console in Chrome... it says:

`Uncaught TypeError: $(...).css is not a function`

This is the simple HTML code:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <ul>
        <li>First item
            <ul>
                <li>Child list item</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Second</li>
        <li>Third</li>
        <li>Fourth</li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the jquery css style:

`$("div#container > ul").css('background-color', 'red')`

What I'm missing?

Comment: Do you have jquery included in the page?

Comment: <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: That probably isn't the only jquery script you're including.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you include jquery? From your html it seems you didn't, in which case it's normal that it doesn't work

Comment: This comes from the Developer console of Chrome, I didn't include it but I can do stuff on the Developer console without adding it.

Comment: @Sonhja Please answer the first question you were asked by clav

Comment: No, I didn't. I thought it wasn't necessary... haven't slept for 2 days... -_-

Answer (score 1):

As answered by Ace in the accepted answer you did not include jQuery. If you did not include the jQuery file how you got it to work in the first place and never got the error that jQuery is missing and $ sign was resolved for you to get the

```
 'Uncaught TypeError: $(...).css is not a function'.
```

Anyways If you want It to work without including jQuery you can use Vanilla JavaScript.
Here is how you can do It:

```
 var myElement = document.querySelector("#superman");
 myElement.style.backgroundColor = "#D93600";
```

Comment: Exactly. you're right. your answer is working in my console.